# Discord Slash Commands python

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Zalogowano jako {bot.user.name}')

@bot.slash_command(
    name="witaj",
    description="Komenda witająca.",
    options=[
        commands.CommandOption(
            name="nick",
            description="Twój nick",
            type=commands.OptionType.STRING,
            required=False
        )
    ]
)
async def witaj(ctx, nick: str = None):
    if nick:
        await ctx.send(f'Witaj, {nick}!')
    else:
        await ctx.send("Witaj!")

bot.run('My token')
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users-------------------\disocrd.py", line 15, in 
@bot.slash_command(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'slash_command'. Did you mean: 'add_command'?

i tried to ask chat gpt

Comment: *Did* you mean `add_command`?

Comment: This code does look a bit mangled and needs to be translated into actual Python.

Comment: Could it be that `slash_command` was added in substitution to `add_command` and you're using an old version?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in discord.py 2.3.0 or higher you can create your command like this:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="test")
@app_commands.choices(option=[
    app_commands.Choice(name="Option 1",value="1"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="Option2", value="2"),
])
async def test(interaction:discord.Interaction,option:
typing.Optional[app_commands.Choice[str]]):
    if option is not None:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"You chose: {option.value}.")
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message("You did not choose.")
```

You need to import these:
`import typing`
`from discord import app_commands`

What the code does:
in the `@app_commands.choices` you give the options to the user
you can also include `@app_commands.description(option="What it does")` above the choices function.

typing is for making the options actually optional and not just choseable but required.

Note: Don't forget to sync the commands!

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    try:
        synced = await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced) commands.}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```